# SQL Server Maximum Transactional Row Insert using Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I'm running into a problem inserting rows from a file with 13,000 rows into a SQL Server 2008 database.  I can take a small chunk of the file and insert it just fine.  I've been able to insert as many as 4000 rows in a single transaction (yes, I'm using transactions), but when I use something higher I get a server 500 error.

Is there a limit on how many rows you can Commit or Rollback in SQL Server using an SQLOLEDB database connection in classic ASP?  If so, how do I increase that?

If not, what other things should I look for in both IIS and SQL Server to ensure I can insert that many rows?

Comment: Have you considered bulk insert or bcp instead of trying to use asp to insert thousands of rows?

Comment: Yes, I have considered that, but to be honest this was the approach I implemented first.  Bulk inserting is a method I may try out as an alternative.

Comment: That would be concerning... you would be effectively allowing any script to execute endlessly which greatly impacts any server performance.  Bad idea IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm not aware of any limit in the #/rows for a single transaction (a "transaction" being a T-SQL "begin tran"/"commit").
2. There are *lots* of limitations in "classic ADO" (the data access API used by "classic" ASP 3.0 and VB6).  But frankly, I don't recognize any of them as being applicable to this scenario.
3. Q: What does your actual ADO "insert" look like?  Could you cut/paste the code here?
4. Q: Have you looked at your IIS server logs?  At your MSSQL server logs?  Are any ADO exceptions being generated (your *are* detecting client side errors, aren't you?).

Comment: Aha... Taking a look at my IIS settings I see I had my script timeout setting too low.  Once I bumped this up the app ran properly.  Thanks for the pointers!